# Strange behaviour of ifelse and fromJSON in pipe

Tags: r

This returns `s` as expected

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

s <- iris[1,] %>% toJSON # create a json object for testing

s %>% { ifelse(nchar(s) > 300, "hi",  s) }
# [1] "[{\"Sepal.Length\":5.1,\"Sepal.Width\":3.5,\"Petal.Length\":1.4,\"Petal.Width\":0.2,\"Species\":\"setosa\"}]"
```

But when `fromJSON` is used, only the first value is returned.

```
s %>% { ifelse(nchar(s) > 300, "hi",  fromJSON(s)) }
# [[1]]
# [1] 5.1
```

How can I get this to return `fromJSON(s)` (i.e. the first row of `iris`) rather than simply the first value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `length(fromJSON(s))` is 5 and when you are using `ifelse` it will return output of same length as your `test` which is 1

```
length(nchar(s) > 300)
#[1] 1
```

hence, it returns only the 1st value i.e `fromJSON(s)[1]`

Based on what you want your expected output you could do

```
library(jsonlite)
ifelse(nchar(s) > 300, "hi",  toString(fromJSON(s)))
#[1] "5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, setosa"
```

OR since we have only one condition to check we can use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse` which is suitable in this case.

```
if(nchar(s) > 300) "hi" else fromJSON(s)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```